# ¿Cómo hacer listas apartir de una lista de caracteres? == python

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Tengo esta cadena de caracteres en un txt, pero no encuentro la manera de dividirla en listas

['up', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up']['Lo0', '10', '0', '5.5.5.5/32', '1', 'LOOP', '0/0']

Todo está información viene de un script que guarda las listas como str y lo que quiero ahora es separar la información en listas como estan lo corchetes o bien al momento de escribir la información hacer un salto de línea.

## este es el script de donde sale el resultado de arriba:

```
show_ip_int_brief = []

device = ConnectHandler(device_type = 'cisco_xe', ip = '192.168.126.129', username = 'cisco', 
password = 'cisco')

output = device.send_command('sh ip int brief')
output2 = device.send_command('show ip ospf interface brief | exclude Interface')
output3 = device.send_command('show mpls interfaces | exclude Interface')
output4 = device.send_command('show ip bgp summary | exclude BGP|Nei')

resultado1 = output.split()
resultado2 = output2.split()
resultado3 = output3.split()
resultado4 = output4.split()

for i in resultado1:
        if i == 'up' or i == 'down':
                show_ip_int_brief.append(i)

print(show_ip_int_brief)
print(resultado2)
print(resultado3)
print(resultado4)

nombre_fichero = 'prueba.txt'

f = open(nombre_fichero, 'w')

f.write(str(show_ip_int_brief))

f.write(str(resultado2))

f.write(str(resultado3))

f.write(str(resultado4)) 

Espero puedan apoyarme GRACIAS!!
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el resultado esperado

Comment: No entiendo... generas unas listas y al final del programa las conviertes en cadena spara volcarlas al fichero. De modo que en el fichero tienes al final la representación de esas listas tal como saldría al hacer un `print()` de las mismas. ¿No es eso lo que quieres? ¿Qué quieres entonces? ¿Sin los corchetes ni las comas ni las comillas, simplemente una secuencia de up, down, etc en una línea cada una? O que cada lista salga tal cual te sale, pero en líneas separadas, una para cada lista?

Comment: La idea es validar la información que se extrae del router antes y después, pero al parecer la lógica que estoy  utilizando no es la correcta...